# Is a stopped local martingale a local martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times, local-martingales

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a filtration of $\mathcal A$
- $M$ be a local $\mathcal F$-martingale on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$
- $\tau$ be an $\mathcal F$-stopping time

> Is $M^\tau$ a local $\mathcal F$-martingale?

With the given assumptions, this claim can be found in the proof of Lemma 15.1 in *Foundations of Modern Probability* by Olav Kallenberg.

I know how we're able to prove the claim using the Optional Sampling Theorem, if $\tau$ takes only countable many values or $M$ is almost surely right-continuous, but I have no idea how I can prove the claim without one of these additional assumptions.

More concretely, he states that if $(\sigma_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is an $\mathcal F$-localizing sequence for $M$, then $(M^\tau)^{\sigma_n}=(M^{\sigma_n})^\tau$ is an $\mathcal F$-martingale. So, maybe the question reduces to the question if a stopped martingale is a martingale, but, again, I'm only able to proof this with the Optional Sampling Theorem and one of its additional assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

To prove a stopped martingale is a martingale, please use the Th.7.29, p.135 in Kallenberg's book.
Since $N=M^{\sigma_n}$ is a martingale and both $N,-N$ are submartingales also, then for $t\ge s$, we have
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}[(N^\tau)_t|\mathcal{F}_s]&=\mathsf{E}[N_{\tau\wedge t }| \mathcal{F}_s] \stackrel{(16)}=N_{(\tau\wedge t)\wedge s}\\
&=N_{\tau\wedge s}=(N^\tau)_s.
\end{align} 
This means $(M^\tau)^{\sigma_n}$ is a martingale.

Comment: There is no Theorem 7.29. The last Theorem of chapter 7 is Theorem 7.23 (strong homogeneity).

Comment: @JGWang's reference is to the second edition of Kallenberg's book. However, the submartingale discussed in that theorem is assumed to be *right continuous*. The issue with Kallenberg's Lemma 15.1 (Lemma 17.1 in the second edition) is that the stopped-process value at time $t$, $(M^\tau)^{\sigma_n}_t = M_{t\wedge\tau\wedge\sigma_n}$ is not guaranteed to be a random variable (let alone $\mathcal F_t$ measurable) without some supplementary condition on $M$; for example, that $M$ be progressively measurable.

Comment: @JohnDawkins 1. So you agree to me that the Lemma, as stated, is wrong. Right? 2. Sure, if $M$ is one-sided continuous and adapted, then $M$ is progressively measurable. So, I could imagine that we can show the desired result in that case. However, how do you prove it? Do you have a reference?

Comment: (I've just looked into the 2nd Edition and the mentioned theorem is just the OST, which as I said in the question cannot be applied.)

Comment: 1. As far as I can tell, the Lemma as stated lacks a necessary regularity hypothesis on the martingale. 2. If $M$ is right continuous then the argument found in Kallenberg is sound. (And when the filtration is right continuous, any martingale admits a right-continuous (and left-limited) martingale modification.)

Comment: @Dawkins Thank you for your correction, you are right.

Comment: @JGWang I followed your advise but I was not able to prove that a continuous stopped martingale is a martingale.. could you provide a sketch of the proof?

Comment: @Buddy_ The 3rd edition of Kallenberg's book published in 2021, if you have any question about it please propose a new question on this site.